# CodeIgniter 3 REST Api cannot read routes

Tags: routes, codeigniter-3, versioning, codeigniter-restserver

I am doing a versioning in my REST API and have it structured this way

example.domain.com 
↳ v1 
↳ v2

It will be browsed like `https://www.example.domain.com/v1` or `https://www.example.domain.com/v2` where each version folder is the root of the REST API. Everything in v1 folder didn't have any issue with the routing but v2 cannot read the route other than `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';` although the v2 is actually a copy of v1. I only changed the `base_url` under `/application/config/config.php` to follow the url I mentioned above.

Below code is the sample of what I have in `/application/config/routes.php` and have **TestingController.php** located in `/application/controllers/api/`

```
$route['test'] = 'api/TestingController';  // new route
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

This is what I have in TestingController.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class TestingController extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index_get(){
        echo 'testing';
    }

}
```

When I browse `https://www.example.domain.com/v2/test` it will give the error `File not found.` but `https://www.example.domain.com/v1/test` is working fine. I don't know where to look cause the codes are the same from both version folders.

I don't have any `.htaccess` file in my root folder of each version (could be the reason?) and if you want to check the REST_Controller it is [here](https://github.com/ajaysoftdeveloper/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php).

Also, as an additional information, I have removed the `index.php` from `$config['index_page'] = '';` under `/application/config/config.php`, which is now an empty string.

**EDIT:**

I just tried adding `.htaccess` but also not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It appears to be working with index.php included `https://www.example.domain.com/v2/index.php/test` . That is very weird as v1 is working without that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the httpd.conf file of your web server and change

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

TO

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Create a .htaccess file in your application root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```